# Android App is rejected from the playstore for having an sdk that transmitts [Advertising ID]

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

My App keeps getting rejected from the play-store for including Advertising ID collection even though I don't have it in my code

I excluded all libs that have it (firebase-analytics) , set google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled to fals

Here's the imported dependencies, the ads-identifier lib is excluded from firebase-analytics

```
implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.4'
implementation 'com.github.abedsh:LoadingButton:v1.5.2'
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:14.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:5.1.1'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.7'
implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.10.3'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
implementation 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.2@aar'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.7.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.3.0'
implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.wooplr:Spotlight:1.2.3'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.0.0'
implementation 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"

// required to avoid crash on Android 12 API 31
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'

//lifecycle
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1"

//facebook
implementation('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:8.2.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

//firebase
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.2')
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
        {
            exclude module: "play-services-ads-identifier"
            exclude module: "play-services-measurement"
            exclude module: "play-services-measurement-sdk"
        }
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'


// Retrofit
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpLogger"

// Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"

// Coroutines
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines"

implementation 'com.mlsdev.rximagepicker:library:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6'

// Room (use 1.1.0-alpha2 for latest alpha)
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.3'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.4.3'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.3'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
// Optional -- Hamcrest library
androidTestImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
// Optional -- UI testing with Espresso
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
// Optional -- UI testing with UI Automator
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation('com.amazon:fortpayment:+:release@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation files("libs/deviceprint-lib-release-2.3.2.aar")
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing this issue & getting rejection for several release attempts. But finally, I found the solution.

Remove permission AD_ID :

```xml
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

Opt-out ads-id collection from facebook SDK by adding this into AndroidManifext.xml :

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.AdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled"
            android:value="false"/>
```

or call in the code by adding this line into your code :

```kotlin
FacebookSdk.setAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled(false)
```

I found the line in the facebook SDK that the default value for collecting advertiser id is `true`. Please have a look [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/1ad4bd9c71ab4b243d3fca04910d6d7de42ae3de/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/UserSettingsManager.kt#L43C1-L43C1) for more detail.

hope it helps